# Selecionar um Item de um List<T> sendo o index igual o valor da iteração do for

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Como posso fazer para selecionar um item de uma lista pelo índice, sendo este, igual o valor da iteração de um `for`?

Eu tentei realizar utilizando LINQ, ao compilar e inspecionar a `StringBuilder` que armazenaria o item, obtenho apenas o nome do `using` concatenado com o nome do projeto e a classe.

```
StringBuilder dados = new StringBuilder(); //Cria StringBuilder
int Contador = (from q in Lista select q.Codigo).Count();  
....

///método que gera string
...
for (int i = quantidade * 10; i < (quantidade * 10) + 10; i++)
{
  if (i >= Contador)
  {
    break;
  }      
  var cod = Lista.Where(c => c.Codigo == i.ToString()).Select(c=>c.Codigo);

  dados.AppendLine(Convert.ToString(cod));
}
```

Resultado da inspeção da `StringBuilder`:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[projetinho.Pedido+Item,System.String]

Por que isso acontece? Como resolver?

Comment: Falta pedaços do código, por exemplo onde está a variável `Contador`. Seria bom conhecer também como é esta lista, embora já dê pra ver pelo menos um erro. O que você chama de armazenar o item? A pergunta não está clara exatamente como a *string* deveria ser montada.

Comment: Olá Maniero, A variável Contador recebe a quantidade de itens na Lista. Esta é uma lista de um objeto. Armazenar o item seria pegar o Código do produto, armazenado na variável `cod` e adicionar ao `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu posso quase garantir que dá pra melhorar isto, mas a pergunta não dá informações que ajudem nisso, então o que posso fazer é indicar a solução pontual e melhorar o que deu para eu ver:

```
var dados = new StringBuilder();
int contador = (from q in lista select q.Codigo).Count(); //queria eliminar isto, não parece fazer sentido
for (int i = quantidade * 10; i < (quantidade * 10) + 10 && i < contador; i++) dados.AppendLine((lista.Single(c => c.Codigo == i.ToString())).Codigo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/BuildLine.cs).

O método `Single()` retorna um item quanto que o `Where` retorna uma lista de itens, tendo um item, basta pegar o campo que deseja dele.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Manieiro... Eu notei que eu fracassei em explicar um detalhe muito importante :(  No caso, o índice do Código teria que ser igual ao da iteração do for. Dessa maneira, só seria adicionado ao `StringBuilder` o código do índice 0, quando o `i` da iteração também for 0...

Comment: E é isso que está fazendo, na verdade eu nem mexi nisso. O que pode estar acontecendo é que não tenha um deles e aí o `SingleOrDefault()` pode ser mais adequado, e aí a lógica teria quer ser ligeiramente diferente, mas de fato eu disse que a pergunta não estava tão clara, mas você não clarificou.

Comment: Realizei a alteração proposta, agora ao percorrer a listam estou obtendo a seguinte exceção `System.InvalidOperationException: 'A sequência não contém elementos de correspondência'`, pelo que entendi isso ocorre por não haver um índice correspondente a iteração?

Comment: Foi o que eu falei no comentário acima.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Maniero. Esta resposta me deu uma boa direção. Depois de um tempo batendo a cabeça descobri as operações `Skip()` e `Take()` onde eu pulo os itens conforme a iteração do `for` e pego os próximos 10.

Answer (score 1):

Está meio difícil de saber o que você quer fazer (para depois pensar no como). Qual o resultado esperado? Seria uma String com 10 códigos dos objetos da lista entre qtd*10 e qtd*10+10?

Nesse caso poderia ser feito com apenas uma query:

```
No[] lista = { new No("7"), new No("16"), new No("18"), new No("19"), new No("20"), new No("21")};
int quantidade = 1;
int start = quantidade * 10;
int end = start + 10;
String[] codigos = lista
              .Where(no => Convert.ToInt32(no.Codigo) >= start &&  Convert.ToInt32(no.Codigo) < end)
              .Select(no => no.Codigo).ToArray();
String saida = String.Join(", ", codigos);
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sfy7Jk